# Netbeans or Eclipse automatise the editing task

Tags: regex, eclipse, netbeans, ide, automation

I have a wired problem with one task I should do. I should find in a source code the strings to be translated and replace them with   equal function, which parameter, should be the string, which is changed.

> `$variable = "Hello world";`

should become

> `$variable = translate ("Hallo world ");

```
>     $variable1 = " This was written in $year . " ;
>     $variable2 = " This was written in $month $year . " ;
```

Should become

> ```
>   $variable1 = tr ( " This was written in % s . " , array ( $year ));
>   $variable2 = tr ( " This was written in % s % s . " ,array ( $month , $year ));
> ```

`

So is there any way in any IDE to markup/highlight those places and let's say with some key shortcut,let's say CTRL+R+W  the IDE will change the string , with replacing it with  a given alhorithm... ?????

Answer (score 0):

With Search->File instead of pressing the "Search" button press the "Replace" button. A dialog will open where you can enter the text to replace with. (This is sort of a global search/replace) You will also be given a chance to preview all the replacements before you apply the change.

Comment: Hi Benjhamin... I am very experienced user actually. What I mean is a tipe of automatic detection of strings. Not only search/replace. The best way would be that i highlight the  result, then with some macro funtion it will add before and after the highlited string tr( and ) characters. Unfortunately, I did found how to add before and after characters with macro, but not how to make them both and at once... because there is no macro function to jump at start of highlighted text and after ...or?